# ¿Cómo renombrar columnas de una tabla SQL mediante una query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Aunque salte error, realiza los cambios.**

La pregunta es simple, en lugar de modificar la tabla desde el diseñador, quiero hacerlo desde una *query*. He encontrado como modificar el `type`, la *descripcion* ... ¡Menos el nombre!

He probado `sp_rename` y no me reconoce las tablas. Comandos como `Rename`, ... No son soportados.

No tengo código útil que mostrar, porque no he conseguido nada, simplemente tengo la tabla por un lado y quiero ponerles nombres nuevos a las columnas.

Podría hacerlo a mano, pero me pica la curiosidad :P

```sql
EXEC sp_RENAME 'OOEMSG.OEUSBY', 'aaaaa', 'COLUMN'
```

> El parámetro *@objname* es ambiguo o el valor de *@objtype (COLUMN)* no es correcto.

Comment: En principio no es tan sencillo, para mi la opción mas viable y que da menos fallos es crear la nueva columna, copiar los datos de la anterior, y luego borrar la antigua.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acabo de hacer una búsqueda rápida  y he encontrado está respuesta de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296669/3683321) en el que utiliza el comando "`sp_rename`"

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.OldColumnName' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

Recuerda utilizar comillas simples para incluir los valores.

Véase: [SQL SERVER – How to Rename a Column Name or Table Name](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/)

y también: [SQL SERVER - Alter table statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/tables/alter_table.php)

**Edit:**

Prueba la siguiente consulta, añadiendo paréntesis tanto a la tabla y la columna del primer parámetro, de la siguiente forma:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME '[TableName].[OldColumnName]' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Acabo de colocar la respuesta a ese código, en principio no veo que este mal... pensaba que era ese hasta que me he encontrado antes con el error. Tengo las mismas páginas abiertas xD

Comment: @GDP acabo de añadir una modificación a ver si así te funciona

Comment: Vale, ya he encontrado el fallo! No hay ninguno >.< Bueno, si. Pero me hace el cambio aunque salga ese error. Y de alli que si vuelvo a intentarlo me salta otro error diferente.Gracias de todas formas por la modificacion, me gusta mas que lo que yo tenía.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciono con la siguiente sintaxis, solo reemplazar lo que esta dentro de las comillas

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'schema:_name.tabla_name.atribute_name', @newname = N'new_name', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le puede ser de utilidad... en caso de tablas temporales el sp debe ejecutarse con indicación de la base de datos tempdb.dbo.sp_rename '#tabla.nombre_col', 'nuevo_nombre_col', 'COLUMN'

Comment: Explica con mas detalle el porque de tu respuesta y como es que resuelve el problema, de lo contrario sera eliminada, date una una vuelta por [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le puede ser de utilidad... en caso de tablas temporales el sp debe ejecutarse con indicación de la base de datos tempdb.dbo.sp_rename '#tabla.nombre_col', 'nuevo_nombre_col', 'COLUMN'

Aclaración: el Stored Procedure (SP) debe ser ejecutado sobre la base de datos del objeto que se desea renombrar.  En caso de tablas temporales la base de datos es tempdb

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).